# iOS – Distribute four views evenly

Tags: ios, autolayout

I want to add four views in a UIView. I want two rows and two columns.
So the top row is 50% of the height of the parent view, and the columns are 50% the width of the parent view.

How would I do this in auto layout? I have considered setting equal widths and heights, but that resulted in not having supplied enough constraints for auto layout.

What should I do to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the views can also be set by using the multiplier also

It can be done with/without constrain to margins, but it will be better if you uncheck the 'constrain to margin' so you will get full area

Detailed Steps:

1. top left view constraints: 
   set top,left constraint to superview
   set equal width,height to the superview
   select the equal heights constraint and set multiplier to 0.5

[image: Set multiplier] 
    do the same for the equal width constraint also

2. top right view constraints:
   set top,right constraint to superview
   select top left view and top right view and select equal widths,equal heighta
3. bottom left view constraints:
   set bottom,left constraint to superview
   select top left view and bottom left view and select equal widths,equal heights
4. bottom right view constraints:
   set bottom,right constraint to superview
   select top left view and bottom right view and select equal widths,equal heights

So your end result will be something like this :

[image]

you can also refer to this image for the constraint as i have displayed the constraint which will be there after completion

Answer (score 2):

1. Set margin contraints to all the 4 views (left, right, top, bottom) to the superview or to the neighbour view depending on the view. For instance, for the top left view set margin contraint to parent for top and left and to the other views for right and bottom.
2. Ctrl+drag from all the other views to the first and set `equal width` and `equal height` constraints.
3. Make sure the margins are equal for all the views (all have constant 0 if you don't need spacing). If they do not have the same margins there will be conflicts.

   ```
   -------------------
   |    |       |    |
   |-[view1]-[view2]-|
   |    |       |    |
   |-[view3]-[view4]-|
   |    |       |    |
   -------------------
   ```

The `-` and `|` represent the margins you need. Also

```
`view2.hight == view1.height` 
`view2.width == view1.width` 
`view3.hight == view1.height` 
`view3.width == view1.width` 
`view4.hight == view1.height` 
`view4.width == view1.width`
```

Comment: So, the top left view should have constraints leading and top to the superview. The top right view should have trailing and top. The bottom left should have leading and bottom and the bottom right should have trailing and bottom.

Then the four views should have equal width and equal height to the superview?

I'm not too sure?

Comment: You have to set constraints between the views too. You need `vertical spacing` between the top left and top right views, same for the bottom ones. And `horizontal spacing` between the top left and bottom left, same for the right ones.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I am still having trouble understanding exactly which constraints I should set.
Could you give a small list of constraints? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll try again!

Answer (score 0):

I do this simply by placing four views evenly on the parent view, and then add 6 constraints to the four subviews.(`top`, `bottom`, `left`, `right`, `equal widths`, `equal heights`)

You can select the four views by holding `command` and click on the four views respectively.

I like to uncheck the `Constraints to margins` so that all the values can be set as 0, which looks more clean.

Hope that helps:)

[See the sample image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zl7eY.png)